# Smallest $k$ such that $\phi(\phi(\phi(..._k(\phi(n)))))=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function

Let $\phi$ be Euler's totient function and $n$ be a positive integer. Let $\phi^k(n)$ denote $k$ sucessive applications of the totient function.

Since $\phi(n)<n$ for all $n\geq 2$, we know that $\exists k|\phi^k(n)=1$ and we can pick a minimal such $k$.

**Question** Are there known asymptotic upper bounds on this better than the trivial $k<n$?

---

We know that $\phi(n)=n-1$ if $n$ is prime. Trivially, $k<n$.

However this upper bound becomes stronger when one accounts for composite numbers: for example, $\phi(n)\leq n-n^{1/2}$ if $n$ has at least $2$ distinct factors. Can we do better than $k<n$?

Comment: no idea. Write a program that takes $n$   from 1 to 100, for each print out n,   k,   and n factored

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is even, if it is not $1.$ Also, $\phi(2m)\leq m.$ So it seems like $1+\log_2(n-1)$ or something like it will work.

Comment: That's a good observation.

Comment: Also,if $n =2^{2^j}+1$ is a Fermat prime, then $k=2^j+1=1+\log_2(n-1).$ So that’s a hard limit.

Comment: It’s possible that there are only finitely many Fermat primes, and thus for $n$ large, we can do better than $1+\log_2(n-1),$ but it is whether there are infinitely many Fermat primes is not going to be settled in the comments here. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phi(2m)\leq m,$ and $\phi(n)$ is even except when $\phi(n)=1.$ So you get $k\leq 1+\log_2(n-1).$

This upper bound can be achieved when $n=2^{2^j}+1$ is a Fermat prime. There might only be finitely man such $n,$ but we can’t do much better for large $n,$ since when $n=2^m,$ $k=m=\log_2(n).$ Indeed, $\lfloor 1+\log_2(2^m-1)\rfloor =m,$ so this is a maximum again.

Comment: Nice...your bound is tighter than mine. I had crossposted. Anyways I deleted my answer...

Answer (score 1):

to check about upper bounds, we print out each time the quantity of interest sets a new record

===================================

```
  n  is between 2^(k-1)  and 2^k.
   diff = n - 2^(k-1)

  n:  2 k:  1 factor n  2 
  n:  3 k:  2 factor n  3  diff 1
  n:  5 k:  3 factor n  5  diff 1
  n:  11 k:  4 factor n  11  diff  3
  n:  17 k:  5 factor n  17  diff  1
  n:  41 k:  6 factor n  41  diff  9
  n:  83 k:  7 factor n  83  diff  19
  n:  137 k:  8 factor n  137  diff  9
  n:  257 k:  9 factor n  257  diff  1
  n:  641 k:  10 factor n  641  diff  129
  n:  1097 k:  11 factor n  1097  diff  73
  n:  2329 k:  12 factor n  17 137  diff  281
  n:  4369 k:  13 factor n  17 257  diff  273
  n:  10537 k:  14 factor n  41 257  diff  2345
  n:  17477 k:  15 factor n  17477  diff  1093
  n:  35209 k:  16 factor n  137 257  diff  2441
  n:  65537 k:  17 factor n  65537  diff  1
  n:  140417 k:  18 factor n  140417  diff  9345
  n:  281929 k:  19 factor n  257 1097  diff  19785
  n:  557057 k:  20 factor n  557057  diff  32769
  n:  1114129 k:  21 factor n  17 65537  diff  65553
  n:  2384897 k:  22 factor n  2384897  diff  287745
  n:  4227137 k:  23 factor n  4227137  diff  32833
  n:  8978569 k:  24 factor n  137 65537  diff  589961
  n:  16843009 k:  25 factor n  257 65537  diff  65793
  n:  35946497 k:  26 factor n  35946497  diff  2392065
```

=============================

Comment: Checking the first N values tells us absolutely nothing about asymptotic behavior, or does it? In any case, I don't see here any kind of answer to the question that was asked - just an attempt as a heuristic approach, but with no attempted conclusion. Or did I miss it?

Comment: @mathguy  interesting to try to prove that there really is a number $n$   between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k$ where the $\phi$  "order" of $n$  is that $k.$  If so, the bound of Thomas is what we call sharp.

Comment: OK - but then, that explanation (of what you were searching for) belongs in the answer. And also, perhaps, with a clarification to the non-professional that this can only help intuition, but no amount of such computations can ever prove - or indeed disprove - rigorously that the bound is sharp.